# Cocoapods: Determine pod version

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swifty-json

How can you tell a) which version of a Pod you're using and b) how to change it?

I'm getting some compile errors with SwiftyJSON and am wondering if it's because I'm using a newer version than I'm expecting.

Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target ‘XXX’ do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
    .......
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `Podfile.lock` file. As documentation says :

> This file is generated after the first run of pod install, and tracks the version of each Pod that was installed.

To change version for example to `2.2` of installed pod use :

`pod 'SwiftyJSON', '2.2.0'`

and run

`pod install`

Hope it help you

Comment: In order to use version 2.2, you have to use `pod 'SwiftyJSON', '2.2'`, not `~> 2.2`. The later means "any version starting from 2.2, but less than 3.0". However, in general your answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks will try tonight.  Does cocoa pods not need the GIT  url?  Saw you removed it in your answer.

Comment: CocoaPods don't need git URL. Look at the `Installation guide` at SwiftyJSON CocoaPods [site](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftyJSON).